# How does .NET create a window?

Tags: .net

For example where is the window created? Is any Win32 native function called? I tried to search in the mscoree.dll but I didn't find a function like CreateWindowEx that could do this.

Comment: Did you look into `System.Windows.Forms.dll`?

Comment: Hmhm, I don't think I will find something if I search for namespaces. Probably I didn't explain it good. I want to know what the "magic" behind .NET is. How and where does it call any native function that will display the window with the user-defined parameters.

Comment: And that is found in System.Windows.Forms.dll. Eventually you want to look at attributes and the `[DllImport]` attribute - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute?view=net-6.0

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that this is an library imported by the framework. Thanks! I will follow this spoor.

Comment: So you didn't know that System.Windows.Forms is the namespace of WinForms? Have you actually used it? Try following the code, start in [`Control.CreateHandle`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.windows.forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,4874c46ec48c63a5,references)

Answer (score 0):

The UI frameworks of .NET, WinForms/WPF and many more, are in general wrappers over native OS UI frameworks (either Win32 on Windows, or Cocoa on macOS, or GTK+ on Linux).

To learn how they wrap over such native APIs, you should search within their source code repos, not `mscoree.dll`,

- WinForms https://github.com/dotnet/winforms
- WPF https://github.com/dotnet/wpf
- GTK# https://github.com/GtkSharp/GtkSharp